# Alamofire 4 - Swift 3 - Credentials and self signed Certificate

Tags: certificate, alamofire, credentials

I am using Alamofire and try to get a JSON Feed from my Server. The Server has a self signed Certificate and Access via User and Password.

here's my Code

```
 let user = "user"
    let password = "password"

    let url1 = "https://10.0.1.2:4711/fhem/?cmd=jsonlist2&XHR=1"
    let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .forSession)

    let serverTrustPolicies :[String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "10.0.1.8": .disableEvaluation
    ]


    let AlamoSession = SessionManager(serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
    AlamoSession.request(url1 )
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response.response)
            print("Result value \(response.result.value)")
            //print (response.result.value?.valueForKey("status"))
    }
```

but it does nor work!

How can i make it?

make a get Request on a https Url wir a self signed Certificate??

In the info.plist in my APP i add the 
App Transport Security Settings - Allow Arbitrary Loads - YES

Answer (score 2):

I ignored SSL errors using this code.

```
import Alamofire

struct WebAPI {
    static let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        switch MyEnvironment.server {
        case .development:
            return Alamofire.SessionManager(
                serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManagerForDevelop()
            )
        case .staging, .production:
            return Alamofire.SessionManager()
        }
    }()

    private class ServerTrustPolicyManagerForDevelop: ServerTrustPolicyManager {

        init() {
            super.init(policies: [:])
        }

        override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
            return .disableEvaluation
        }
    }

}
```